# Why does the 32-bit version of QGIS 3.4 works better (does not regularly crash) than the 64-bit on my 64-bit W10Pro laptop?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, windows-10, 64bit, 32bit

I was initially using the 64-bit version then it started crashing. First, it crashed whenever expressions/Python was involved. Then, it crashed when I was closing it. This happens in both the 64-bit 3.4 and 3.10 LTR versions.

Even when installed through the OSGEO4W installer, the problem persists.

Also, is it true that with the 32-bit, I'll be using half the RAM?

Comment: Please edit your post to include a single, focused question. Remember that you can always ask multiple questions as separate posts.

Comment: `Also, is it true that with the 32-bit, I'll be using half the RAM?`   That would depend on what you are trying to do, it's all about the maximum addressable memory (of which RAM is a part), on a 32-bit OS you can address up to 4GB, whilst on a 64-bit OS it's about 16 Exabytes.

Comment: If it starts crashing like this, it helps to clean up the user profile (located at C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles). But unfortunately no idea why QGIS starts behaving like this sometimes and how to prevent this.